# The maximum of $a+b+c$ satisfies $2^n=a!+b!+c!$ for $n,~a,~b,~c\in\Bbb N$

Tags: number-theory

How to find the maximum of $a+b+c$ satisfies $2^n=a!+b!+c!$ for $n,~a,~b,~c\in\Bbb N$? I can only deduce that $a,~b,~c$ cannot be $\geq 3$ simultaneously.

Comment: Well, you can push that idea a bit further.  Say $a=2$ and $b,c≥3$.  Then $b!+c!=2(2^{n-1}-1)$ so the right hand is divisible by only one power of $2$.    That means that at least one of $b,c$ must be $3$.  And so on.

Comment: First prove $n \neq 0$.  Then note the right side is even.  What combinations of even/odd work for the factorials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wolog assume $a \le b \le c$.  So $a!|b!, c!$ so $a!|a! + b! + c!=2^n$. But as $3\not \mid 2^n$ we must have $a < 3$ so so $a = 1, 2$.

If $a = 1$ then $2\le b! +c! = 2^n-1$ and that is odd .  So $b!$ and $c!$ can't both be even.  So $b! = 1$.  And we have $1\le c! = 2^n - 2 = 2(2^n-1)$.  $2^n - 1$ is odd so only a single power of of $2|c!$ so $c \le 3$.  If $c = \color{red}1,2,3$  we can have $2 + c! = \color{red}3, 4, 8= \text{no power of two}, 2^2, 2^3$.

If $a= 2$ then $4 \le b! + c! = 2(2^n-1)$ with $2^n-1$ being odd. $b!|b! +c!$ so $b \le 3$ so $b = 2, 3$.

If $a = b=2$ then $6\le c! = 2^n -4 = 4(2^{n-1}-1)$ where $2^{n-1}-1$ odd so only $2^2$ can divide $c!$ and $2|3!$ and $8|4!$ so $c< 4$ and $c = 2,3$.  $2!+2!+2! = 6 \ne 2^n; 2! + 2! +3! = 10\ne 2^n$.

$a =2; b=3$ then $14 \le 2! + 3! + c! = 2^n$ and $c! = 2^n - 8= 8(2^{n-1}-1)$ and argument should be familiar now.  $2^3|c!$ but $2^4 \not \mid c!$ so $4 \le c \le 5$.  So $a=2; b=3; c=4,5$ so $a! + b! + c! = 2!+3!+4! = 2+6 + 24=32^5$ or $a!+b!+c! = 2!+3!+5! = 2+6 + 120=128= 2^7$.

So that's that.  $n = 7$ is the highest possible result.

Answer (score 2):

We can bound the solutions by considering the factors that the sum of factorial on the right can have.

For definiteness assume $a\le b\le c$.  Then if $a\ge 3$, all the factorials are multiples of $3$ which contradicts their sum being a power of $2$.

So $a\le 2$, meaning $a!\in\{1,2\}$.  Then the remaining two factorials can't be multiples of $4$ or else (given the possible values of $a!$) the sum would be an odd number greater than $1$ or twice such a number, which is again no good.  As $4|4!$ we then must have $b\le 3$.

So $a\le 2, b\le 3$, and therefore $a!+b!\le 8$.  Given this constraint and taking a cue from the reasoning above, you are to find a power of $2$ that can't divide $c!$ and use that to find a limit on $c$.  This completes the bounding of the solutions.

You may then try all candidates that fall within those bounds, starting with the maximum candidate since the maximum of $a+b+c$ is asked for.

If you complete the remaining steps correctly, you should not need very many trials at the last stage.